# Using regex to find descriptions in the javascript files of MVC project?

Tags: c#, regex, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application where I pass certain translations to my views so I can show my pages in different languages (the translations are used in the corresponding javascript file, not in the razor view). Now I have a `List<string>` for every view which contains the descriptions of the translations I need, which is a real pain to maintain of course. If I change a single javascript file, I need to update the corresponding collection etc.

Now I had a crazy idea, in all my js files I use `dictionary.find('<description>')` to get access to the translations. Would it be a bad idea to populate my lists when the model is first accessed by using a regex on the javascript files? It would look something like this:

```
protected static List<string> Descriptions;

private static Model()
{
    string basePath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Scripts");
    string fileName = Path.Combine(basePath, $"{modelName}.js");
    string javascript = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    Regex regex = new Regex(@"dictionary\.find\('(.+?)'\)");
    var matches = regex.Matches(javascript)
                       .Cast<Match>()
                       .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
                       .ToList();
}
```

This code basically reads the javascript file that is used for the view and finds all the words that are used between `dictionary.find('...')`.
I've already tested this, and it seems to work but my question is:

**How bad of an idea is this?** Or is it good? My models/scripts are named very consistently etc so that wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: If the description has no newlines in it, and no escaped sequences, then it is quite all right.

Comment: You can always write a test that verifies all your files match your expected format as well. Then whenever someone else comes in to make changes, there is a safety net.

Comment: @SpykeBytes Great idea, this would indeed be of great use when my colleagues work on the project.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So you don't think there's any disadvantages? It's not that hard obviously to just add descriptions when I change the javascript files, but I'm lazy and it's just so ugly having 100's of lines of descriptions inside a class

Comment: @AlexanderDerck: Regex  is meant to reduce tons of lines of code.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that you would want to store data in file types meant for that.

I think there is no problem having a conventions based approach to this, but you might be better suited putting your `<description>` data in a JSON file. The JSON file could live right next to your js files.

If you do that, you can just load up your translations by using a json serializer and you won't have to muck around with regex.

EDIT: I think it would still be a good idea to have a test verifying that all of your expected files do exist and match your expected format.

Comment: But then I need to manually say which translations I need again per javascript file. For example now I add a new method for an ajax request in the js file and I need `dictionary.find('noConnectionError')`, then I need to update the file too to include `"noConnectionError"` (which is easy to forget) :/

Comment: Not if you use naming conventions and have an automated test. But this is the classic argument of convention vs configuration.